Identifying definition and theorem counters halfway through document
I am currently creating a latex article for a large-scale assignment for a class. In it, the numbering system for the definitions and theorems needs to change halfway through the document. In one section, definitions and theorems get different counters without section numbers. But in section 2, they use the same counters. Here is a visualization of what I am trying to achieve:
SECTION 1
definition 1
theorem 1
theorem 2
definition 2
theorem 3
etc...

SECTION 2
definition 2.1
theorem 2.2
theorem 2.3
definition 2.4
theorem 2.5
etc...

I have been successful in adding the section number to the end of them by using \renewcommand, but I have not been able to make their counters the same after the switch to section 2. Is this possible to do?
Thank you so much for the help!

Welcome to tex.sx.  It should be possible to do this -- \renewcommand can be used within the document; it isn't necessary to restrict it to the preamble.  I'd do the redefinition immediately after the section heading, and reset the counter(s) to zero at the same time.

Define special theorems for the first section and, inside a group, change the standard ones to the special ones.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% define the environments for the paper
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

% define the environments for the first section
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{firsttheorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{firstdefinition}{Definition}


\newenvironment{specialsection}{%
  \RenewEnvironmentCopy{theorem}{firsttheorem}%
  \RenewEnvironmentCopy{definition}{firstdefinition}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{specialsection}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{definition} text \end{definition}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}
\begin{definition} text \end{definition}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}

\end{specialsection}

\section{Now the fun begins}

\begin{definition} text \end{definition}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}
\begin{definition} text \end{definition}
\begin{theorem} text \end{theorem}

\end{document}



That worked perfectly for me. Thank you for the help!

One approach would be to use AMS theorems that look similar but are defined differently:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{sharedTheorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{sharedDefinition}[sharedTheorem]{Definition}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{definition}
    First definition
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
    First theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
    Second theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
    Second definition
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
    Third theorem
\end{theorem}
etc...

\section{Second Section}
\begin{sharedDefinition}
    First definition
\end{sharedDefinition}
\begin{sharedTheorem}
    First theorem
\end{sharedTheorem}
\begin{sharedTheorem}
    Second theorem
\end{sharedTheorem}
\begin{sharedDefinition}
    Second definition
\end{sharedDefinition}
\begin{sharedTheorem}
    Third theorem
\end{sharedTheorem}
\end{document}



Feasibility test:
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{foo}
\newcounter{bar}

\makeatletter
\let\c@foo=\c@bar
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{foo}
\thefoo~\thebar

\stepcounter{bar}
\thefoo~\thebar
\end{document}

